# ggplot bar graph by percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I am trying to make a bar graph showing ages of first alcohol use by county by percent. I am not quite sure where the mistake is and would appreciate another set of eyes.

Data is publicly available here: https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/dataset/national-survey-drug-use-and-health-2020-nsduh-2020-ds0001 although I have cleaned it on my computer.

The percentages are definitely not out of 100 and the numbers are not adjusting for population. They are the same as my chart showing raw numbers.

```
palc.age.ct<-data1.cleaned%>%
  mutate(ALCTRY= na_if(x=ALCTRY, y="Never Used"))%>%
  drop_na(ALCTRY)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=ALCTRY, fill=COUTYP4))+
  geom_bar (position = "dodge") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))+  
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(title = "First Alcohol Use by Age and Locality",
       x="Age Initiated", y="Number Initiated")+
  scale_color_viridis(option = "D")
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Please provide a MRE by pasting the output of `dput(data1.cleaned)`, then it's easier to help you, thanks! In general, I find it easier to calculate the percentages before plotting them and then use `geom_col`. Then you can also easily determine what should be 100% (I guess you want to split it by `COUTYP4`?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recreating everything you did like labelling the bins, but based on the data you can do something like below. Note that you need to include the `position = "dodge"` in the bar chart where you want to calculate the percentage. Otherwise the calculation is done in a different geom than the one that is creating the grouped bar geom. Which is the reason for your issue.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

NSDUH_2020 %>% 
  select(alctry, COUTYP4) %>% 
  mutate(altcry = if_else(alctry > 66, NA_integer_, alctry),
         COUTYP4 = forcats::as_factor(COUTYP4)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(altcry)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = alctry, fill = COUTYP4)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = .1)) + 
  scale_x_binned()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think it was the dodge and scale_y issue, but it is working for me now. I thought this would auto adjust for population and help me see percentages within populations, but this chart is the same as the total population chart I'm getting. For example, urban populations are much higher than rural populations, so I was hoping this would help me visualize the percentage of 10-19 year olds, with the assumption that this looks to be so far apart because there are more kids in cities than in rural areas. Should I be taking a different approach?

Comment: With population research you need to scale your figures to reflect the differences in population densities. Like first time drinkers per 100.000 persons. This is why mortality figures are mentioned as number of deaths per 100.000. This can give you a comparison per country / county / region. The problem you have with these figures is that you only have a variable called population density, which is not granular enough. With this data you can't say anything definite whether rural kids are more likely to drink at an earlier age than non-rural kids.

Comment: I asked this question wrong. I don't mean populations like they mean in epidemiology. But the total number of people who answered the survey were broken down as 50 people linked to rural, 100 people linked to small metro, and 200 people linked to large metro the percentages would be different, correct? Right now they are not adjusting that way. Appreciate any thoughts on how to update my code.

Comment: @KimberlyBoland, No idea, reading chapter 7 of the codebook, they use different minimum size requirements depending on state and below that different sizes per dwelling units. I'm not sure, but I expect that all info in the data has been corrected for this otherwise the data would not be usable. Try to contact someone at samhsa who can give you information on how they corrected this info and how you can compare this data between the population areas.